# Information sent in DELETE body is not processed by CherryPy

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, cherrypy, http-delete

I have this Javascript (jQuery) code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: `/rest/order`,
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: { "magentoid": order_id },
    success: function(data) {
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    }
});
```

And when checking this call in the Chrome developer console, I can see the body is sent as well:

[image]

However, in my CherryPy implementation, that data seems to be completely ignored:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_out()
def order(self, supplier = None, magentoid = None, dropship = None):
    logging.info(f"supplier: {supplier}, magid: {magentoid}")
```

results in:

```
INFO:root:supplier: None, magid: None
```

When I make the call in Javascript with `$.post`, it does work:

```
$.post(
    "/rest/order",
    { "magentoid": orderid, "dropship": $("#dropship").is(":checked") },
    function(data) {
    }
).fail(function() {      
});
```

and this shows in my CherryPy log:

```
INFO:root:supplier: None, magid: M13000000063
```

**Update**, also when I change `DELETE` into `POST` in the `$.ajax` call, the data goes away.

Comment: Weird: https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/_modules/cherrypy/tutorial/tut03_get_and_post.html#WelcomePage

Comment: @mplungjan yes, GET and POST seem to work I guess, but DELETE does not.

Comment: https://docs.cherrypy.dev/en/latest/pkg/cherrypy._cprequest.html#cherrypy._cprequest.Request.method

Comment: You want methods_with_bodies as in the above link.